Captured arabian man tells his magical story
As a child, probably somewhere around 1994, I remember seeing a movie on TV with an old Arabian setting. It included a man who was supposedly captured by a group of others who was forced to tell them his story.
This story was cut in a few episodes, all of which happened in Arabia, and some seemed to include magical items (a ring?) the man had in possession, but later lost. In one episode, two people were running around a very large pool in a courtyard.
As far as I could tell, it was a long and well made movie.

There was a miniseries called "Arabian Nights" which fits your description, but it aired in 2000.

@steelerfan I've had a look at the trailer - it's different. Thank you tho!

@DanielStowers No, completely different setting.

Sounds like one of the movies about the "little Mook".
They are based on a story from the German writer Wilhelm Hauff (published 1826).
The frame story is about an old man (Mook) who is bullied by kids for being small.
Then the story of his life is told.
The setting is Arabic, and his life includes magic tokens and spells.
He found wealth and fame, but figured out that it wont make him happy and gave it up.
The German Wikipedia lists 4 movies:

1921: Der kleine Muck (Regie: Wilhelm Prager)
1944: Der kleine Muck (Regie: Franz Fiedler; schwarz-weiß)
1953: Die Geschichte vom kleinen Muck (Regie: Wolfgang Staudte; DDR) (I guess, this is yours; see below.)
1971: Der kleine Muck (Regie: Otto Anton Eder; TV-Film, Österreich).

I found only one of them on IMDb: 
"The story of little Mook" from 1953 (GDR).
This is the one I have seen myself, and it includes a race around a pool between young Mook and a professional runner. 
(As far as I remember, the pool is not part of the original story, so this might be specific for this particular film.)
Furthermore, in this film the kids chase old Mook into his house. 
He sits on top of a shelf, where they cant reach him and he tells his story while the kids are around him (this is the being captured by a group part). 
(In the original, one of the kids hears the story from his father, not from Mook).
At least in Germany, this film is still repeated on TV and even in some arthouse movie theatres. 
So watching it 1994 would be possible. 
PS: And yeah, great special effects (considering it's age)!
PPS: The pool still exists in the Filmpark Babelsberg (near Berlin).
Someone made a photo and added the movie poster. 

I believe this is it! I now realize I misremembered a few things, and I'm amazed someone still found it. Thank you!

Your welcome!  You gave a could description that made it easy for someone who saw it a dozen times ;)
